# json type as postgres query parameter with npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql

How can i make a query with Json object as `IDbDataParameter` using NpgSql provider? Why does not this work?

```
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter() as NpgsqlParameter;
        parameter.ParameterName = "json";
        parameter.Value = @"[""text""]";
        parameter.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Json;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

and i receive an error then - Message: 42601: (syntax_error) "INSERT contains more target columns than expressions"

Comment: The code you posted is missing the actual SQL query, and the error message indicates that's where your error is. Please post the full SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the evening questions, you know ). The recipe above works fine. The value can be a, string rendered, json without quotes surrounding. The error was come from my custom query serializer. Shay, thank u for the advice, the way for testing u suggested made me found a solution quick )